# Java Program: finding smallest and largest number of 3 numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The code below works fine for the largest value but for the smallest value it is displaying: *smallest number is 0* for any 3 values I input. Would greatly appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClass{


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // declare and create array object
            // declare smallest and largest int variables 
            int[] numbers;
            numbers = new int[3];
            int smallest = numbers[0], largest = numbers[0];

            // create Scanner object
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            // prompt user 
            System.out.print("Please enter 3 numbers: \n");
            // use for loop to obtain user input
            for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
                numbers[counter] = input.nextInt();
            } // end obtaining input

            // for loop to find largest and smallest values
            for (int i=0 ;i< numbers.length; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
                    smallest = numbers[i];
                } // end finding smallest
                if (numbers[i] > largest) {
                    largest = numbers[i];
                } // end finding largest number       

            }

            System.out.println("largest number is "+largest);
            System.out.println("smallest number is "+smallest);

        }   

}
```

Comment: You're setting `smallest` and `largest` before you read any numbers in. That means they'll both be zero. This is okay for largest, but not for smallest.

Comment: But I thought that _int smallest=numbers[0]_ means that it will take it as the first element in the array not as the value 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smallest is always initialized as 0 here: `int smallest = numbers[0]`. Unless the user enters a value smaller than 0, smallest value will stay 0. Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE`) instead to ensure that the smallest number will actually be selected.

Comment: But I thought that _int smallest=numbers[0]_ means that it will take it as the first element in the array not as the value 0

Comment: @Amanda yes, but you read the value of `numbers[0]` before assigning a value to it. Since the array is initially filled with 0, you'll get 0 as `smallest`. You could either read the intial values for `smallest` and `largest` after reading the input, or use my solution. NOTE: the evaluation for the largest element worked only because you've only used positive integers (same problem as for `smallest`).

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `smallest` to `0`, so if none of the numbers in the array are less than `0`, you'll still get `0` as the result. Instead initialize it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is the highest value the integer datatype can have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getMaxMin(int a, int b, int c){
        int max=a;
        int min=a;
        if(b>max){
            max=b;
        }
        if(c>max){
            max=c;
        }
        if(b<min){
            min=b;
        }
        if(c<min){
            min=c;
        }
        System.out.println("min="+min);
        System.out.println("max="+max);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare and create array object
        // declare smallest and largest int variables 
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[3];

        // create Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // prompt user 
        System.out.print("Please enter 3 numbers: \n");
        // use for loop to obtain user input
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
            numbers[counter] = input.nextInt();
        } // end obtaining input

        //Use in built Math.min and Math.max to get smallest and largest numbers
        System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", "smallest number is ", Math.min(numbers[0], Math.min(numbers[1], numbers[2])));
        System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", "largest number is ", Math.max(numbers[0], Math.max(numbers[1], numbers[2])));
    }
}
```